# How to show 2 fragments with different toolbars?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have two fragments.I want to show first fragment under blue toolbar and second one under grey one.

[image]

How to implement this?

Comment: create two toolbar layouts and set them in your xml

Comment: In addition to what @justDroid suggested, use a theme without ActionBar.